# Printing Long without warning

Tags: c, pointers

In my code I have a void * pointer created which stores a pointer to a long

```
void *ret = (void *) (long) number);
```

All I am trying to do is print it:

```
fprintf(stderr, "ld", ret);
```

However I get the warning:

```
warning: format ‘%ld’ expects argument of type ‘long int’, but argument 4 has type ‘void *’
```

I unfortunately have to use the void *ret. Is there anyway to cast this so I avoid the warning? After countless google searches I couldn't find a solution. Thanks!

Comment: `fprintf(stderr, "ld", (long int)ret);`

Comment: Why don't you cast it the same as you do in the declaration?

Comment: Why do you use a pointer to store an int?

Comment: Sounds like an "xy problem". What is the actual problem you are trying to solve? Why must you use `void*`?

Comment: "I am trying to print it" -- what is "it"? There's two possibilities -- the pointer, or the long it's pointing to.

Comment: Are you trying to print the pointer `ret` or the integer value it points to?  The post is not clear in what you want, other than to avoid a warning.

Answer (score 2):

```
void *ret = (void *) (long) number);
```

This is a syntax error.

If it really stores a pointer to a `long`, it looks like this:

```
long n = 42;
void *ret = &n;
```

You can print it like this:

```
printf("%ld\n", *(long *)ret);
```

Answer (score 1):

Don't print `long`, print pointer instead - `fprintf(stderr, "%p", ret)`

Answer (score -2):

## 1:      `void *ret = (void *) (long) number);`

change to:  `void *ret = (long*)&number;`

## 2: `fprintf(stderr, "ld", ret);`

change to: `fprintf(stderr, "%ld", *(long*)ret);`

## 3: my suggests

change it to:  `long* ret =  (long*) &number);fprintf(stderr, "%ld", *ret)`

Comment: Why the cast in `(long*)&number`?